# Validating an array of objects in DTO NestJS

Tags: validation, nestjs, dto

I am try to make put request with this JSON
for example:

```
{
    "token": "a7b067b4c86eaf1033fd22f083195c4f",
    "messengerAccounts": [{
        "messengerAccountID": "testuser",
        "messengerType": "viber"
    }]
}
```

But i have problem with validation. I tried using ParseArrayPipe but it doesn't work, similar questions didn't help me find a solution. It’s also worth noting that I’m passing not only an array of objects, but just a string with a token and I don’t understand how to combine it all

my controller:

```
@Controller('cash-register')
export class CashRegisterController {
  constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {}
  @Put()
  @UsePipes(ValidationPipe)
  async updateCashRegister(
    @Body(new ParseArrayPipe({ items: Tags })) dto: UpdateUsersDto,
  ) {
    return this.usersService.updateCashRegister(
      dto.token,
      dto.messengerAccounts,
    );
  }
}
```

my dto:

```
export class UpdateUsersDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  token: string;
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @Type(() => Tags)
  messengerAccounts: Tags[];
}

export class Tags {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  messengerAccountID: string;
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  messengerType: string;
}
```

Main problem in dto.messengerAccounts:

```
Argument of type 'Tags[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[{ messengerAccountID: string; messengerType: any; }]'.
  Target requires 1 element(s) but source may have fewer.
```

Comment: Which line emits this error?

Comment: dto.messengerAccounts

Comment: Could you please provide a snippet of the `this.usersService.updateCashRegister` function? Obviously the error relates to that function.

Comment: try remove `new ParseArrayPipe({ items: Tags })` in your @Body